# Selecting sub element with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have the following type of HTML code to work with:

```html
<tbody id="id_tbody">
 <tr id="tr_project_0" class="project_tr clr01 hover" data-select-value="0" style="border-top: 1px dotted #B4B4B4;">
  <td class="txtC">
   <a href="/173537">173537</a>
                </td>
                <tr id="tr_research_0" style="" class="">
   <table id="table_project_num_173537" class="tblTypeInner01 cl_tr_research_node">
    <tbody>
     <tr id="tr_research_node_173537_0" class="research_tr" data-select-value="442879,0,173537,2">
      <td class="txtC"><a href="/442879">442879</a></td>
```

And the following Python code:

```html
project_list = browser.find_element_by_xpath( "//tr[@class='project_tr clr01']" )
survey_list = project_list.find_elements_by_xpath( "//tr[@class='research_tr']" )
last_survey = survey_list[0]
survey_go = last_survey.find_elements_by_xpath( "//td[@class='txtC']" )
print survey_go[0].text
```

What I expect is for the script to return `"442879"`, however it returns `"173537"`.
Why does `survey_go` return the sub elements of `project_list` instead of `survey_list[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the dot in beginning of XPath to point on context node (`project_list`):

```
survey_list = project_list.find_elements_by_xpath( ".//tr[@class='research_tr']" )
```

The same for `survey_go`:

```
last_survey = survey_list[0]
survey_go = last_survey.find_elements_by_xpath( ".//td[@class='txtC']" )
```